# delete old files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

okay maybe this sounds simple, but it has been a bit challenging to me

I have a directory called backups and it has (backup files + other files)

backups files:

```
../backups/backup-2013_03_03.zip
../backups/backup-2013_03_05.zip
../backups/backup-2013_01_01.zip
../backups/backup-2013_08_16.zip
../backups/backup-2013_02_28.zip
../backups/backup-2013_01_21.zip
../backups/backup-2013_03_29.zip
../backups/backup-2013_04_05.zip
```

I'm trying to delete backup files older than 90 days.

```
 find /var/tmp/stuff -mtime +90 -print | xargs /bin/rm
```

seems to work, but I'm not able to limit the search to backup files only. "files which starts with backup*"

I have tried adding "-iname backup" option to find command argument, thinking it would do the trick but it doesn't seems to work. 
Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `-exec` option of `find` along with `-iname`. Since you want to delete only files, you would need to specify `-type f`

```
find /var/tmp/stuff -type f -iname 'backup*' -mtime +90 -exec rm {} +
```

---

If you prefer `xargs` like me

```
find /var/tmp/stuff -type f -iname 'backup*' -mtime +90 -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

**Note :** It's recommended to use `find -print0` with `xargs -0` to avoid weird file name caveats

Answer (score 3):

The parameter to `iname` matches against the full filename, so you need a trailing wildcard:

`find /var/tmp/stuff -mtime +90 -iname "backup*" -print | xargs /bin/rm`

You could also use find's `-exec` argument, but personally I find the syntax quite arcane. I prefer xargs.
`find /var/tmp/stuff -mtime +90 -iname "backup*" -exec /bin/rm '{}'`

Or, as damienfrancois points out, GNU find can take a `-delete` argument. This is the best solution because a) it is shorter and b) it is more efficient because the deletion happens within the `find` process. `exec` and `xargs` will both spawn one new process per file to delete. Source: [GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html) However, as wildplasser points out, it could also be dangerous - `-delete` will remove directories by default. To only delete files, use `-type f`.

`find /var/tmp/stuff -type f -mtime +90 -iname "backup*" -delete`

Comment: and you could use the `-delete` option of `find` rather than `xargs`

Comment: Wow, yes. Not only did I not know `-delete` existed, I then did not know it would silently delete directories.

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe through grep before calling rm. Something like:

```
find /var/tmp/stuff -mtime +90 -print | grep 'backup-' | xargs /bin/rm
```

while the find utility has all kinds of options to single handedly do this, including the deleting as noted in other answers, I can never remember any but the most basic options.

```
find "stuff" | grep "some_other_stuff" | xargs "do_stuff"
```

seems much easier to remember for me.